# What is the difference between these two different lines of Objective-C, and why does one work and not the other?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, memory-management, nsmutablearray, nsarray

If I try and release `tempSeedsArray` after `seedsArray = tempSeedsArray` , I get an `EXEC_BAD_ACCESS`, and Instruments shows that `tempSeedsArray` has been released twice. Here is my `viewWillAppear` method:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {  
    NSString *arrayFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"SeedsArray" ofType:@"plist"];  
    NSLog(@"HIT!");  
    NSMutableArray *tempSeedsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:arrayFilePath];  
    seedsArray = tempSeedsArray;  
    NSLog(@"%u", [seedsArray retainCount]);  
    [seedsArray sortUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];  
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];  
}
```

`seedsArray` is an NSMutableArray set as a `nonatomic` and a `retain` property, and is synthesised.

However, if I change `seedsArray = tempSeedsArray` to `self.seedsArray =  tempSeedsArray` (or `[self seedsArray] = tempSeedsArray` etc.), I can release `tempSeedsArray`. Could someone please explain simply to me why this is, as I am very confused!

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `seedsArray = ...` assigns to the `seedsArray` *field*.
2. `self.seedsArray = ...` invokes `setSeedsArray:`, which is the setter for the `seedsArray` *property*.

If you `@synthesize seedsArray`, these two form will behave almost the same (see @JeremyP's comments below), but if you define your own setter, only the second form will set the property and invoke your code.

Comment: so then why is it that although I have synthesized `seedsArray`, `seedsArray = ...` and `self.seedsArray = ...` seem to behave differently? (I do not have a custom setter)

Comment: Because those two lines are not the same if you synthesize seedsArray.  The first one merely assigns the tempSeedsArray pointer to the seedsArray instance variable.  The second sends a setSeedsArray: message to the object with the property which does three things: 1. retains the object referenced by tempSeedsArray, 2. assigns tempSeedsArray to the instance variable for the property, 3. releases the object previously referenced by the instance variable.

Comment: +1 @JeremyP, I didn't consider the `retain` property qualifier.